# workbench apresenta erro e nao conecta

Tags: mysql

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

workbench tinha paraado de conectar, entao reinstalei ele, mas agora o erro é esse, tenho o xampp instalado e ele nao inicia o mysql, ja verifiquei e nao tem nenhuma conexão ativa na porta 3306, nao encontro nenhum processo ou serviço ativo do mysql, o que pode ser?

Answer (score 0):

Seu banco MySql não está subindo o serviço, veja nos logs do `Xampp` qual é o motivo do erro.

[image: Exemplo]

Comment: InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
 InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
 InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
 File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-12-17 18:30:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-12-17 18:30:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.10 started; log sequence number 300297; transaction id 171
2019-12-17 18:30:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool

Comment: @iasmim aparentemente não consigo ver um problema no log, recomendo que abra uma nova pergunta no stackoverflow detalhando com o este log para outros usuários possam te ajudar. Não se esqueça de fechar está pergunta.